# Get access to resx file

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

In my project I have resx file. MyFile.resx

If I use in my code:

```
MyFile.PropertyOneName; MyFile.PropertyTwoName
```

Everything works great and I can have access to these properties values

But what if I want to pass string parameter as a propertyName and get that by reflection:

typeof(MyFile).GetProperties returns 0 elements while I have a lot properties in it :/

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MyFile.ResourceManager.GetString("PropertyOneName", MyFile.Culture)
```